# Using tense after the word “did”

Tags: past-tense, infinitives, do-support

Using tense after the word “did”.

I know that we use the present tense after “did”; however, how should I apply this rule in the following sentences.

A.  “He did go to his grandma’s home yesterday, but his sister went/go to her school.”

If I go with the rule then it should be (but his sister go to her school), but this sounds awkward to me.

B.  Did he eat his lunch, and go/went to his father’s shop this morning?

And again, (“go” to his father’s shop this morning) looks uncommon.

Comment: No, we use the infinitive after the auxiliary verb "did", **not** the present tense. In A. you should use past tense "went" since it is part of a separate main clause. In B. it should be the infinitive "go" since it is not part of a separate main clause, but head of a verb phrase as complement of "did" (compare: "Did he eat and go?")

Answer (score 2):

We use the infinitive (not the present tense) after *did* (the axillary verb) in questions and negative sentences. This is correct.

> Did he eat his lunch, and go to his father’s shop this morning?

We usually use the past form of the verb in the affirmative sentence. This would be correct.

> He went to his grandma’s home yesterday, but his sister went to her school.

But you can use emphatic *did* with the infinitive in the affirmative sentence in some situations to emphasize the action.

> He did go to his grandma as he had promised, but his sister didn't. She went to her school.